# Visual Studio View Browser not working on Core 2.0 Web app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm running a simple ASP.NET Core Web Application and I when I attempt to right click\View in Browser on any of my .cshtml content pages (i.e. lives here => localhost:1234/pagefolde/mypage) it always navigates to localhost:1234.

I have Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise) - v15.6.7

I've even been following the thread here about other people having similar problems [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167130/view-in-browser-shortcut-not-working.html) and their alleged fix didn't seem to make a difference for me at all.

Thank you.

Comment: They're not HTML files. You don't get to a view via the folder path it exists in, even with Razor Pages. There is a route that must be hit that will eventually render the view. Since the routing can vary on a number of different factors, it is usually a happy accident if view in browser actually *does* end up loading the particular view you were after. Long and short, there's not really anything you can about this. It's just the way things work.

Comment: Also, regarding the linked issue: that's referencing Web Forms pages (ASPX). Those actually *are* routed to via file path, so it's trivial for something like view in browser to load it up directly. It has no application to an ASP.NET Core site.

Comment: Is there not a workaround to get this to work - i.e. for instances if my Razor Page is /folder/razorpage.cshtml then I know I can get there by going to localhost:1234/folder/razorpage - I'm actually surprised there isn't an extension, or something.  Would there not be a way to (somehow) setup the route(s) in Startup.cs and hack up something so that it works (just hypothetically) using a controller?

Comment: Well just about anything is possible if you want to dig into Visual Studio extension development, but that's a little extreme for something solved by just clicking a link or manually typing something into the address bar. Short of that or unless someone else has already created such an extension, you're out of luck.

Comment: Figured as much, and yes I agree that it is extreme.  Thanks.